# Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to 'WebApplication.Title via a reference conversion, boxing conversion,

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, selectedindexchanged, object-initializers

here is the situation.

-There are two listboxes(lb1-lb2). In one(lb1) all data displayed that taken from database.

-When I want to click data from lb1 the content has to be displayed in other listbox(lb2).

-They are two different tables that has relationship in database.

-I've used entity framework and to reach objects of datables I did object initializer.

-I've handeld the selectedIndexChanged property to provide that dynamism I've done the following code

```
 Title choosen;
    private void lb1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lb1.SelectedIndex == -1) return;
        choosen = lb1.SelectedItem as Title; //underlines and gives error in here
    }
```

it throws an error as: Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to 'WebApplication2.Title' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion

What should I do? What am I missing? thanks for your help

Comment: What are the columns in `Title` table?

Answer (score 0):

you Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to your class Title

try this

```
    Title choosen;
    private void lb1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lb1.SelectedIndex == -1) 
            return;
        choosen.name = lb1.SelectedItem.Text;//set object properties
        choosen.value= lb1.SelectedItem.Value;

    }
    public class Title { //your Title class has some properties so..i assume some properties
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly convert `SelectedItem` to `Title`

try below

```
choosen = new Title(){ TitleText = lb1.SelectedItem.Value};
```

I assume you have column called `TitleText` in your title table, change as you need

Comment: nope It doesnt work.. It has to display on lb2 when I clicked from lb1 , under SelectedItemChange event the thing that you said did not handled